# How do I import this XML in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, gml

This is the content of the file (excerpt):

```
<geometry>
    <geometry_type>MULTISURFACE</geometry_type>
    <multi_surface>
        <id_geometry>885734</id_geometry>
        <curve_polygon>
            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
            <exterior_ring>
                <compound_curve>
                    <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                    <linestring>
                        <point>
                            <x>2679799.926</x>
                            <y>1126099.279</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                        <point>
                            <x>2679749.926</x>
                            <y>1126099.279</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                    </linestring>
                    <linestring>
                        <point>
                            <x>2679521.42</x>
                            <y>1127489.018</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                        <point>
                            <x>2679523.657</x>
                            <y>1127487.384</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                    </linestring>
                </compound_curve>
            </exterior_ring>
            <interior_ring>
                <compound_curve>
                    <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                    <linestring>
                        <point>
                            <x>2677898.741</x>
                            <y>1126459.361</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                        <point>
                            <x>2677897.591</x>
                            <y>1126457.533</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                    </linestring>
                    <linestring>
                        <point>
                            <x>2677897.591</x>
                            <y>1126457.533</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                        <point>
                            <x>2677899.375</x>
                            <y>1126456.364</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                    </linestring>
                    <linestring>
                        <point>
                            <x>2677899.375</x>
                            <y>1126456.364</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                        <point>
                            <x>2677900.543</x>
                            <y>1126458.158</y>
                            <id_geometry>0</id_geometry>
                            <snap_type>0</snap_type>
                        </point>
                    </linestring>
                </compound_curve>
            </interior_ring>
        </curve_polygon>
    </multi_surface>
</geometry>
```

I tried Drag and drop + Add Vector Layer but it didn't work. Error: `Invalid Data Source: ...\plot.xml is not a valid or recognized data source`.

The data looks like WKT but converted to XML...

Comment: Drag and drop + Add Vector Layer but it didn't work. Error: `Invalid Data Source: ...\plot.xml is not a valid or recognized data source`

Comment: please update your question with the details and any error messages

Comment: what happens if you change the extension to gml?

Comment: It doesn't work, they are not the same structure at all. Mine is closer to WKT.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to work because the XML has no schema, therefore QGIS doesn't know how to read it. You are going to need to convert it into something it can read.

For XML formats that would be GML or KML. If you are only dealing with the a few files it might be easiest to convert them by hand, if you have a lot of data you will need to use XSLT:

[XSLT Introduction](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp)

XSLT isn't exactly user friendly, so it might be worth paying someone on [Upwork](https://www.upwork.com/) to do it for you.